# VF page issue in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, slds

I have a VF page created for Salesforce classic using Lightning Design System. The page works fine in Classic. But when I try to view it in Lightning Experience, it doesn't load (CSS) properly. Any reasons for the issue? I have enabled the 'Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app' checkbox as well. Please note that I added static resource to load the LDS css too but it didnt work out.

```
<apex:page id="sConfigId" controller="VF_Controller" showChat="false" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="true" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" docType="html-5.0">

    <head>
        <title>Title</title>

        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_SR, '/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_Connect, '/js/jquery-ui.js')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_Connect, '/css/jquery-ui.css')}" />

        <!-- Import aljs and momentjs for Date pickers -->
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_Connect, '/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_Connect, '/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js')}"/>
        <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.SR_Connect, '/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css')}" />

        <!-- Import Datatables and jquery -->
        <!-- Import aljs and momentjs for Date pickers -->
        <!-- Import SDLS --> 
        <apex:slds />

    </head>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add the Screenshot of the VF page in Lightning Environment for reference and indicate what is wrong with that?

Comment: hey, attached the screen shot. Inspect doesn't show me any errors too

Comment: Which specific CSS is not loading? Are you expecting to show your VF with lightning styles? If so, try setting `lightningStylesheets`. This will work ok if you have used standard apex tags in your page. Any custom styles my still need updating to work with lightning version though.

Comment: Yes. I tried adding lightningStylesheets="true" on <apex: page lightningStylesheets="true"> but still doesn't work. any idea?

Comment: In lightning experience, after rendering the page if you look at the source, are you able to identify which css is not loading?

Comment: What I have experienced with exactly this setting, is that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Not helpful, I know, but with me, apparently time heals all wounds. Meaning: after a day or so, the lightning stylesheets actually got loaded. Don't aske me why or how.

Comment: Well i did a mistake. I couldn't add the class="slds-scope" on body tag. It may help you too probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should work if you adds **class="slds-scope"** to your body element.

```
<body class="slds-scope">
   ...
   your html code
   ...
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **lightningStylesheets** in your apex:page tag.
See example below

`<apex:page id="sConfigId" controller="VF_Controller" showChat="false" showHeader="true" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="true" showQuickActionVfHeader="false" docType="html-5.0" lightningStylesheets="true"`>

[Winter 18 – Automatic Styling of Visualforce Pages in Lightning Experience](https://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/winter-18-automatic-styling-of-visualforce-pages-in-lightning-experience/)

Comment: Added already. Nothing changed